# How to popup the alert - Django template

Tags: django, django-views

I have wrote the template for user input the info , each user will have the separate password. I would like to validate the password when they input , if the password is incorrect they will got the popup message said "wrong password .." or sth like that.

I tried to import messages library, however it doesn't work correctly, could you please help assist ?

below is my code:

views.py

```
from .models import Register1
@csrf_exempt
def reg(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.POST.get('password') =="Password":
            print(request.POST.get('password'))
            if request.POST.get('phone') and request.POST.get('name') and request.POST.get('email'):
                post=Register1()
                post.phone= request.POST.get('phone')
                post.name= request.POST.get('name')
                post.email= request.POST.get('email')
                post.save()                
                return render(request, 'posts/reg.html') 
        else:
            print(request.POST.get('password'))
            messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'Wrong Password')
            return render(request,'posts/reg.html')

    else:
            return render(request,'posts/reg.html')
```

templates/posts/reg.html

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container mt-3">

<body>
<div class="col-9">
    <!-- <h2>Input your password to continue proceed</h2>
    password: <input id = "pwd" type="password" name="password"/><br/>


    <div class="col-3 "> -->
        <!-- <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="validate()">proceed</button>
    </div> -->
</div>
<div class="col-6 mt-3">
    <form action="" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <h2>Input your password to continue proceed</h2>
        password: <input id = "pwd" type="password" name="password"/><br/>    
        <div class="col-3 ">
        Phone: <input type="text" name="phone"/><br/>
        <!-- Name: <br/>
        <textarea cols="35" rows="8" name="name">
        </textarea><br/> -->
        Name: <input type="text" name="name"/><br/>
        Email: <input type="text" name="email"/><br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Post"/>
    </form>
</div>
</body>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The messages framework allows you to set messages in one request, and retrieve them in another. You need to update your template to retrieve them and specify how to [display them](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/messages/#displaying-messages).

As an example, you could choose to use a [Bootstrap Alert](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/alerts/):

```
<div class="col-6 mt-3">
    {% for message in messages %}
    <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">{{ message }}</div>
    {% endfor %}
    <form action="" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        ...
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @Matt, btw when i access to the web interface, default it said the message "'Wrong Password'" , how  it just popup the message when user click on the submit button ?

Comment: The message may have appeared because it had not yet displayed. The messages framework stores them until displayed, after which they are deleted. If the problem continues, I suggest that you change your view code so that the page is reloaded after a successful POST. Check the example view code in the [official Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/intro/tutorial04/#write-a-minimal-form).